# Can't adjust list as i want it to be

Tags: python, sqlite, loops

I want to have my `initial` in the data list of every tuple's last.

```
names = ['ID', 'NAME', 'CLASS', 'BOOK', 'RETURN'] 
initial = [2213, 2211]
sql = "UPDATE [LIBRARY] SET {0}{1}WHERE {2} = ?".format(" = ?, ".join(names[0:]), " = ?", names[0])
print(sql) 

data = [(2217, 'ARJ', '10A', 'NONE', 'NONE'), (2216, 'JOHN', '10A', 'NONE', 'NONE')]
for i in range(len(data)):
        data = [list(d)[0:] for d in data] 

        lst = [list(d)[0] for d in initial]
list=[]
for i in range(len(lst)):
        list.append(lst[i])

print(data+ list)
```

> output : [[2217, 'ARJ', '10A', 'NONE', 'NONE'], [2216, 'JOHN', '10A', 'NONE', 'NONE'], 2213, 2211]

I want the output to be :

> [[2217, 'ARJ', '10A', 'NONE', 'NONE', 2213], [2216, 'JOHN', '10A', 'NONE', 'NONE', 2211] ]

Comment: Your inner lists  in the output are mixing `[]` and `()` — is that a typo? Do you want tuples or lists?

Comment: Oh sorry for that. Yes it is a typo

Comment: Actually i want list

Comment: Okay I got it. Just have to use `mixed = [list(d)[0:] for d in mixed]` after 4 line in the answer of @Mark Meyer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can zip the lists together and add the tuples in a list comprehension:

```
initial = [2213, 2211]
data = [(2217, 'ARJ', '10A', 'NONE', 'NONE'), (2216, 'JOHN', '10A', 'NONE', 'NONE')]

mixed = [a + (b,) for a, b in zip(data, initial) ]

print(mixed)
# [(2217, 'ARJ', '10A', 'NONE', 'NONE', 2213), (2216, 'JOHN', '10A', 'NONE', 'NONE', 2211)]
```

If you want lists instead you can turn the tuple into a list as you process it:

```
mixed = [list(a) + [b] for a, b in zip(data, initial)]
```

or

```
mixed = [[*a, b] for a, b in zip(data, initial) ]
```